# How to run an animation on classes instead of ids?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I have something like this set up on my page.

```js
function wiggle(){
  var parent = document.getElementById("wiggle");

  var string = parent.innerHTML;
  parent.innerHTML = "";
  string.split("");
  var i = 0, length = string.length;
  for (i; i < length; i++) {
      parent.innerHTML += "<span style='--n:"+ (100 * i - 10000 + 'ms') + ";'>" + string[i] + "</span>";
  }

}

wiggle()
```

```css
#wiggle span{
  animation-delay: var(--n);
  animation: wave 2s linear var(--n) infinite forwards running;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes wave{
  0% {top: 0px;}
  25% {top: -4px;}
  50% {top: 0px;}
  75% {top: 4px;}
  100% {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<h1 id="wiggle">This text should wiggle...</h1>

<h2 id="wiggle">...while this text should not.</h2>
```

As this stuff works now, the Javascript splits the id, letter by letter, into their own `<span>` tags while the CSS gives them their own animation delays and says how high the waves of the animation should be.

But I want this animation to apply to multiple headers on my page, so I want to switch the code to look for and act on classes instead of ids. But changing `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` and changing `#wiggle` to `.wiggle` didn't work, and the animation doesn't display. Is there any way to get the Javascript to look for classes without breaking it?

Comment: Try: `getElementsByClassName('wiggle')[0]` or `querySelector('.wiggle')` This will find the first element with the class. If you want all of them: `getElementsByClassName('wiggle')` or `querySelectorAll('.wiggle')` and use the `forEach` method to loop over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the class, if you don't want it to wiggle.

```js
const wiggle = (elementOrSelector) => {
  const element = typeof elementOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrSelector)
    : elementOrSelector;
  if (!element.classList.contains('wiggle')) {
    element.classList.add('wiggle'); // Or control with a data attribute
  }
  const text = element.textContent;
  element.textContent = '';
  element.innerHTML = text.split('').reduce((html, c, i) =>
    (html + `<span style="--n:${10 * i - 10000}ms;">${c}</span>`), '');
};

const wiggleAll = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.wiggle').forEach(wiggle);
}

wiggleAll(); // Wiggle all

wiggle('.wiggle-single'); // Wiggle this manually
```

```css
@keyframes wave {
  0%   { top:  0px; }
  25%  { top: -4px; }
  50%  { top:  0px; }
  75%  { top:  4px; }
  100% { top:  0px; }
}

.wiggle span {
  animation-delay: var(--n);
  animation: wave 2s linear var(--n) infinite forwards running;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wiggle">This text should wiggle...</h1>

<h2>...while this text should not...</h2>

<h1 class="wiggle">...but this should.</h1>

<h1 class="wiggle-single">Manually wiggle...</h1>
```

Alternatively, you can add a class to the span elements and change your CSS rule. This way you decouple the span from its container.

```js
const wiggle = (elementOrSelector) => {
  const element = typeof elementOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrSelector)
    : elementOrSelector;
  const text = element.textContent;
  element.textContent = '';
  element.innerHTML = text.split('').reduce((html, c, i) =>
    (html + `<span class="wiggler" style="--n:${10 * i - 10000}ms;">${c}</span>`), '');
};

const wiggleAll = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.wiggle').forEach(wiggle);
}

wiggleAll(); // Wiggle all

wiggle('.wiggle-single'); // Wiggle this manually
```

```css
@keyframes wave {
  0%   { top:  0px; }
  25%  { top: -4px; }
  50%  { top:  0px; }
  75%  { top:  4px; }
  100% { top:  0px; }
}

.wiggler {
  animation-delay: var(--n);
  animation: wave 2s linear var(--n) infinite forwards running;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wiggle">This text should wiggle...</h1>

<h2>...while this text should not...</h2>

<h1 class="wiggle">...but this should.</h1>

<h1 class="wiggle-single">Manually wiggle...</h1>
```